# Logon as a service for virtual accounts

Tags: windows, service-accounts

I have a Windows Internal Database installation running with its default settings. I have the required "Logon as a service" permissions configured as follows:

```
Administrators
ALL SERVICES
LOCAL SERVICE
NETWORK SERVICE
NT SERVICE
```

After the first server restart since SQL installation the service fails to start. I add an entry for `NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES` in the service logon permissions and everything works again. The thing I don't quite grasp is that why wouldn't `NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES` be already included either with `NT SERVICE` or `ALL SERVICES` entry?

Technically the service is configured to logon with `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID` so there is backslash after `NT SERVICE` but I don't think that would be the actual root cause here.

Answer (score 0):

`ALL SERVICES` is not by itself a valid name, so I expect it is being ignored:

```
C:\working>icacls test /grant "ALL SERVICES":(OI)(CI)(F)
ALL SERVICES: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

C:\working>icacls test /grant "NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES":(OI)(CI)(F)
processed file: test
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

`NT SERVICE` is described in [KB243330](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) as "an NT Service account prefix" and prefixes do not normally have any meaning by themselves; it is recognized as a valid name (which surprises me) but I don't believe it has any members.  So it is not surprising that this was not sufficient.

`NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES` is the correct way to permit virtual service accounts to log in.